# Inflating android native UI in react native screen

Tags: android, react-native

There is a full react native screen in my app, that screen consists of a flatlist (react native component) in that flatlist i want to add a header but that header view is in native. 
I have added package in my react activity like this

```
 .addPackage(new MultimediaViewPackage())
```

**My MultimediaViewPackage**

```
 package com.o1.shop.reactModules.resellerFeed; 
    public class MultimediaViewPackage implements ReactPackage {


        @Override
        public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }


        @Override
        public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            return Collections.<ViewManager>singletonList(
                    new MultimediaViewManager()
            );
        }
    }
```

**MultimediaViewManager**

```
public class MultimediaViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<MultimediaHolder> {

    private static final String MULTIMEDIA_VIEW = "MultimediaView";

    /**
     * @return the name of this view manager. This will be the name used to reference this view
     * manager from JavaScript in createReactNativeComponentClass.
     */
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return MULTIMEDIA_VIEW;
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses should return a new View instance of the proper type.
     *
     * @param reactContext
     */
    @Override
    protected MultimediaHolder createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        MultimediaHolder a = new MultimediaHolder(reactContext);
        a.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 300));
        Log.e("HEIGHT", "createViewInstance: HEIGHT" + a.getLayoutParams().width);

        return a;
    }
}
```

**I get the height too printed as 500** so this method is getting called too.

**MultimediaHolder**

```
class MultimediaHolder extends LinearLayout {

    public MultimediaHolder(Context reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

    }
}
```

**Multimedia.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { requireNativeComponent, View } from "react-native";

class Multimedia extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <MultimediaView />;
  }
}

Multimedia.propTypes = {
  ...View.propTypes
};

const MultimediaView = requireNativeComponent(`MultimediaView`, Multimedia);

export default Multimedia;
```

Any help will be appreciated